# An easy way of iterating over all unique pairs in a collection

Tags: c#, collections

I have a c# 3 `HashSet` object containing several elements. I want to check something between every pair of them, without repeating [(a,b)=(b,a)], and without pairing an element with itself.
I thought about switching to some sort of List, so I can pair each element with all of his following elements. Is there an option of doing something like that with a general, unordered, `Collection`? Or `IQuaryable`?

Comment: So, just to be clear: you want to take a _set_, and the from it produce a _sequence_ of all of its _two-element subsets_, yes?

Comment: All of the unique two-element subsets, so that if (a,b) is in there, (b,a) will not.
I think I'll go with the ToList() method, or maybe just switch my set with a list and be done with it...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For this, it would be easier when you can access them with an index, and although there exists an ElementAt<> extension it probably is faster to use .ToList() first.

When you have an addressable list:

```
for (int i = 0; i < list.Count-1; i++)
  for (int j = i+1; j < list.Count; j++)
     Foo(list[i], list[j]);
```

Answer (score 2):

How about using the [Distinct method that takes an IEqualityComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338049.aspx)?

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something here, but how I can use an IEqualitycomparer to make sure all pairs are unique? I can easily use it to make sure an element won't pair with itself, but that is not enough...

Comment: A HashSet only contains unique elements, you would have to create all tuples first. Seems overly complicated.

Comment: mm.. or maybe I can make the comparer for a pair of elements, and use it on a distinct over an IEnumerable of all pairs. I'll check it out later. thanks.